# How to get eclipse to build .F files?

Tags: eclipse, fortran, gfortran

I have preexisting fortran source code that builds without error in visual studio with ifort (or OneAPI) that consists of multiple ".F" files and a main program. Trying to get this to build in eclipse, I created a new eclipse gfortran project and added all files, but eclipse gives the error `Nothing to build for project ...`, and I think the reason is it simply ignores the ".F" files.
Under project Properties > Fortran General > Source Form, "*.F" is visible.

Comment: What kind of project did you set-up? How exactly? What exactly are you doing before the error message appears? Clicking at something?

Comment: I did what will work in most IDEs: New > Project > Fortran Project (selecting Executable : Gnu Fortran on Windows, Toolchain GCC Fortran), Drag/Drop/Add ".F" files into Project Explorer, Project > Build All (or Build Project). This should be very simple. It's literally a one line shell command ("gfortran file1.F file2.F ... Main.F -o main.exe") but somehow eclipse makes it hard, even for an experienced software developer. I don't know how eclipse calls the compiler and linker. How do I see that command? It appears to be ignoring the ".F" files and I don't know why or how to change that.

Comment: If I create a project in the exact same way and do New > Fortran Source File > main_program.F, the same thing happens, eclipse ignores it. On the command line, the program builds an executable with: "gfortran main_program.F".
```

      program main_program
          implicit none
          print *, "Hello World"
      end program main_program
```

Comment: Are you using Photran? What version of Eclipse? Check https://help.eclipse.org/latest/topic/org.eclipse.photran.doc.user/html/basic/WritingCode.html

Comment: Eclipse for Scientific Computing
Version: 2023-06 (4.28.0)
Build id: 20230608-1333
Under about Eclipse IDE > Installation details, it has org.eclipse.photran.* installed.

Comment: In a simple one-file project that I mention above, if I rename the .F file to .f90, it builds without error.